# Como puedo multiplicar strings dentro de un array

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un problema para tratar de resolver el siguiente ejercicio:

Consigna
Escribí una función que reciba dos parámetros: un string S y un integer R.

La función debe devolver un string donde los caracteres consecutivos de S no se repitan más que R veces.

Tiene que devolver un string con el texto limpio y la cantidad de caracteres repetidos correcta.

Ejemplos:
Ej: "AAAAAFFFFOOOA", 2 => "AAFFOOA"
AAAFFFOOOA
Ej: "111223333344", 1 => "1234"
Ej: "AABB", 1 => "AB"

lo que tengo hasta ahora es esto y no se como tomar los elementos del array y multiplicarlos despues por el integer que tendria que pasarle por el input.

```js
function Limpiar()
{
    var str=document.getElementById('a').value;
    

    var str1=[];
    for (var i=0;i<str.length;i++)
    {
        var key=str[i];
        if(str.indexOf(key,i+1)==-1){
            str1.push(key);
        }
    }

  
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="practica1.js" ></script>

    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body> 
 <h1>Calcular Mayor, Menor e Igual</h1>

 <input type="text" placeholder="Texto" name="string" id="a">
 <input type="number" placeholder="Numero B" name="N" id="b">

 <button onclick="Limpiar()">Limpiar</button>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira esto puede servirte:

```js
function Limpiar() {
  var str = document.getElementById('a').value;
  var duplicar = document.getElementById('b').value;
  const unicos = [];
  const cadenafinal = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    const elemento = str[i];
    if (!unicos.includes(str[i])) {
      unicos.push(elemento);
    }
  }
  console.log(unicos)
  for (var i = 0; i < unicos.length; i++) {
    let valor = unicos[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < duplicar; j++) {
      cadenafinal.push(unicos[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(cadenafinal)
  document.getElementById('a').value = cadenafinal.join("");;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="practica1.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Calcular Mayor, Menor e Igual</h1>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Texto" name="string" id="a">
  <input type="number" placeholder="Numero B" name="N" id="b">
  <button onclick="Limpiar()">Limpiar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias es justo lo que necesitaba